# get json data inside html object, and object is from ajax get response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

how to get just json data,from this reponse

```js
$.get('http://localhost:8000/json', function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

response is :

```
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
    {"logo":"logo.jpg"}
</div>
```

how to get value inside response function, so i can get like alert(response.logo) means logo.jpg

Comment: Why don't you fix the format of your response to *not* have the html in it, and instead just return the JSON part?

Comment: i try to hide response from my codeigniter controller.. just that..  i know thats is bad idea.. any suggestion for me?

Comment: The response to an Ajax request doesn't get displayed in the page, it is returned directly to your JS, so there is nothing to hide. Again, remove the HTML and just return the JSON part. (I guess if the user entered that URL directly into their browser *then* it would display the JSON, but so what? You can't prevent the user seeing the JSON if they are determined.)

Comment: how stupid iam.. that's absolutely right.. thanks dude.. for make me realize it.. thanks dude.. yes so nubie right.. hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is fix your response,
but, as a workaround, you can parse the string you get with jquery...

```js
var str = '<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;"> {"logo":"logo.jpg"}</div> '

var el = $(str)

var inner = el.html()

console.log(JSON.parse(inner))

console.log(JSON.parse(inner).logo)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow.. thats cool... like you see the response is from echo inside codeigniter controller.. and i just wanna hide em with display=none, any suggestion for eficient and save passing variable from php to javascript? cos i newbe on this.. thanks maioman..